# 'lambda expression' cannot be used it is not part of the ISO - 2 C# (Only Framework 2.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks, lambda

I am forced to downgrade an project from framework version 4.0 to version 2.0.

The following code used to work without any problems:

```
deleteButton.Click += ((sender1, e1) => DeleteAnswer(sender1, e1));
```

I am simply assigning an Click Event for an ASP Button Controller.

But After targeting the project for framework version 2.0, I received this error:

> 'lambda expression' cannot be used it is not part of the ISO - 2 C#

What does this mean and what is the solution?

Comment: Why do you need to downgrade?

Comment: @SargeBorsch The Hosting Server only supports 2.0

Comment: Maybe it's better to change hosting server then...

Answer (score 0):

I means you can't use lambda expressions with .NET 2.0.  You are going to need to go back to 'traditional' delegates.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?